# Why is my textbox not populating?

Tags: php, html

The code below will echo the passed value/variable in the php portion of the code only in line 2 which verifies that the variable is being passed. The textbox in the html portion remains blank and does not populate.

I have removed all other code trying to find my error, what have I done wrong?

```
<?php
echo $new_customer . $_POST['search'];
?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <body>
    <input type="text" name="customer_name" value="<?php echo $new_customer; ?>" id="customer_name">
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: [I can't reproduce the issue](http://codepad.org/mjk2JR1L). Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Have you looked at the resulting html source code to see what is being output? You might be missing a closing tag or quote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need value for `$new_customer`.

```
<?php
$new_customer =  $_POST[search];
?>
```

Unless you assign value to `$new_customer`, you can't print it in html.

Comment: There are cases where the op's code would put _<b>E_NOTICE : </b> type 8 -- Undefined variable: new_customer_ as value of the input. Just saying...

Comment: doesn't     $var = $_POST['some_value'];     assign the posted value to the variable?  In this case assign the passed value to $new_customer variable.

Comment: Finally saw it. In my mind I had typed $new_customer = $_POST['search'] which is what it should be.  But instead I had $new_customer . $_POST['search'] with a period instead of equal sign.  I know it had to be a simple syntax error.